# Define same function name in one C project

Tags: c, function

I have a main file that includes two h files that both of them has the function foo(). 
What happens when i call foo from main? Which one will be chosen?

Thanks

Edit:
I saw your answer, so what can you say about this: (its actually working) :

```
///////////// FILE: q7lib.h
#include <stdio.h>
void foo ();
/////////////  END OF FILE
///////////// FILE: q7lib.c
#include "q7lib.h"
void foo () {
    printf ("q7lib: foo");
}
/////////////  END OF FILE

///////////// FILE: q7.h
#include <stdio.h>
void foo ();
/////////////  END OF FILE
///////////// FILE: q7.c
#include "q7.h"
void foo () {
    printf ("q7: foo");
}
/////////////  END OF FILE

///////////// FILE: q7main.c //////////////
#include "q7.h"
#include "q7lib.h"
int main () {
foo ();
return 0; }
///////////// END OF FILE /////////////////
```

Comment: What happens if you try it?

Comment: Do these files both contain a function *definition* or merely a function *declaration*?

Answer (score 3):

You won't get as far as calling the function because the linker won't accept your program. The linker will reject your program when it encounters multiple definitions of the same function.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will give you an error telling you it is an ambiguous call to the function.